# Python Subplot function parameters

Tags: python, plot, scipy

I am having a hard time with putting in the parameters for the python subplot function.

What I want is to plot 4 graphs on a same image file with the following criteria

```
left
space
     right
space
left
space
     right
```

I have tried different ways of the 3 numbers but the output doesnt show up correctly.

Comment: Do you mean a 2x2 grid or a 1x4 grid?

Comment: Thats what I am confused about. There are 4 graphs and the way spacing works is that I can just create a 3X2 grid and only plot on 1st and 3rd.. where the 2nd row becomes a space.. so I think it should be 7X2

Comment: You are using matplotlib right?

Comment: yes.. i just cant figure out the sequences of the 3 inputs for the graphs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,4)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,5)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,8)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, the not-so-easily-found documentation regarding the sublot function template is as follows:

```
subplot (number_of_graphs_horizontal, number of graphs_vertical, index)
```

Let us investigate the code from Joe Kington above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,4)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,5)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4,2,8)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)

plt.show()
```

You told *matplotlib* that you want a **grid** with **4 rows and 2 columns** of graphs. *ax1*, *ax2* and so on are the graphs that you add at the *index positions* which you can read as the third parameter. You count from left to right in a row-wise manner.

I hope that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib provides several ways deal with the deliberate placement of plots on a single page; i think the best is ***gridspec***, which i believe first appeared in the 1.0 release. The other two, by the way, are (i) directly indexing *subplot* and (ii) the new *ImageGrid* toolkit).

*GridSpec* works like grid-based packers in GUI toolkits used to placed widgets in a parent frame, so for that reason at least, it seems the easiest to use and the most configurable of the three placement techniques.

```
import numpy as NP
import matplotlib.pyplot as PLT
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.cm as CM

V = 10 * NP.random.rand(10, 10)  # some data to plot

fig = PLT.figure(1, (5., 5.))  # create the top-level container

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)   # create a GridSpec object

# for the arguments to subplot that are identical across all four subplots,
# to avoid keying them in four times, put them in a dict 
# and let subplot unpack them
kx = dict(frameon = False, xticks = [], yticks = [])

ax1 = PLT.subplot(gs[0, 0], **kx)
ax3 = PLT.subplot(gs[2, 0], **kx)
ax2 = PLT.subplot(gs[1, 1], **kx)
ax4 = PLT.subplot(gs[3, 1], **kx)

for itm in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4] :
    itm.imshow(V, cmap=CM.jet, interpolation='nearest')

PLT.show()
```

---

Beyond just arranging the four plots in a 'checkerboard' configuration (per your Question), I have not tried to tune this configuration, but that's easy to do. E.g.,

```
# to change the space between the cells that hold the plots:
gs1.update(left=.1, right=,1, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)

# to create a grid comprised of varying cell sizes:
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4, width_ratios=[1, 2], height_ratios=[4, 1])
```

[image]